# Change line color depending on where it sits on different divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to use jQuery to make my border line change color depending on where it sits on the divs. I set it `position: absolute` and it is laying on both divs. I was trying to make the line on the top div to be the color grey and the line on the bottom div to be white. I want to dynamically change the color depending on which section it is over.

https://codepen.io/asreenz/pen/MWpGMQO link to Codepen.

```html
<div>
    <div class="line">
    </div>
  <div class="top-box"></div>
  <div class="bottom-box"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.line{
  width:0px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -225px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-box{
  width:100vw;
  height:500px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.bottom-box{
  width:100vw;
  height:500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.line-grey{
  color:#8a96a3;
}
.line-white{
  color:white;
}
```

```js
var top1height = $(".top-box" ).height();
var bottom1height = $(".bottom-box" ).height(); 
var linePosition = $(this).offset();
if(linePosition > top1height){
   $(".line").addClass(".line-grey"); 
} else {
   $(".line").removeClass("line-grey"); 
}
if(linePosition > bottom1height){
   $(".line").addClass(".line-white"); 
} else {
   $(".line").removeClass("line-white"); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site works best when you post your code, [not images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67862578/edit) to include your code. You may also include a link to Codepen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an event listener to watch for when the page scrolls.
to keep the code DRY you can re-use a lot of the code and reduce the amount of javascript you have to write and maintain.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const formatLine = function () {
        var topBox = $(".top-box");
        var bottomBox = $(".bottom-box");
        var line = $(".line");
        var positionFormatter = function (line, box, className) {
            const lineTop = line.offset()['top'];
            if (lineTop > box.offset()['top'] &&
                lineTop < (box.offset()['top'] + box.height())){
                line.addClass(className);
                return true;
            } else {
                line.removeClass(className);
            }
            return false;
        }
        positionFormatter(line, topBox, "line-grey");
        positionFormatter(line, bottomBox, "line-white");
    };
    formatLine();
    $(document).scroll(formatLine);
});
```

```css
.line{
  width:0px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-box{
  width:100vw;
  height:500px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.bottom-box{
  width:100vw;
  height:500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.line-grey{
  border-color:#8a96a3;
}
.line-white{
  border-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="line">
    </div>
  <div class="top-box"></div>
  <div class="bottom-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what about when it hits directly in the middle of two divs? it retains the grey color, but i need it to immediately change its color depending on what it is hovering over, not only when the line is 100% on one side or another